# Qt4 existing slots are not recognized

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, signals-slots

I am currently trying to complete a project using Qt4 and C++. I am using buttons to switch between states. While trying to connect the buttons' clicked() signals to the textEdit to display the relevant state, I got stuck on an error:

> Object::connect No such slot
>   QTextEdit::append("move state")
>   Object::connect No such slot
>   QTextEdit::append("link state")

Only, QTextEdit definitely has an append(QString) slot.

Any ideas?

Some code samples:

```
QPushButton *move = new QPushButton("Move");
connect(move, SIGNAL(clicked()), textEdit, SLOT(append("move state")));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't pass in an argument (literally) to the append() slot when making a signal to slot connection.

You refer to it like a method signature:

```
SLOT(append(QString)) //or const QString, I'm not sure
```

If you need the textbox to append the words "move state" every time that button is clicked, then you should define your own slot that will do the append.

Comment: This does not work. Did you mean to put the method signature in quotations? Thanks.

Comment: Oh shit, sorry, I work in both Qt and PyQt and used the wrong syntax. Yes, definitely did not mean the quotes lol...

Answer (score 4):

Chris has it in a nutshell.

That is one of the many reasons I like boost::signals a lot more (you are allowed to use boost::bind).  You are basically going to need to create another function that captures the signal and then performs the append.

```
...

QPushButton *move = new QPushButton("Move");
connect(move, SIGNAL(clicked()), textEdit, SLOT(MoveState()));
}

...

void MyTextEdit::MoveState()
{
    append("move state");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `QSignalMapper` to pass a hard-coded argument to the text edit's slot.

Example:

```
QSignalMapper* signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
QPushButton* move = new QPushButton("Move");
signalMapper->setMapping(move, QString("move state"));
connect(move, SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QString)), textEdit, SLOT(append(QString)));
```

Beware of the bugs in the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you will have other `QPushButton`s that will cause other states to occur, you could put them inside a `QButtonGroup`. Then, you can use an enumeration, such as `{ MOVE_ID, STOP_ID, ... }` to refer to the possible states.

```
QPushButton* move = new QPushButton( "Move" ) ;
QPushButton* stop = new QPushButton( "Stop" ) ;
QButtonGroup* buttonGroup = new QButtonGroup() ;
buttonGroup->addButton( move, MOVE_ID ) ;
buttonGroup->addButton( stop, STOP_ID ) ;

// Connecting QButtonGroup to writing function
connect( buttonGroup, SIGNAL( buttonClicked( int ) ),
         textEdit, SLOT( append( int ) ) ) ;
```

In `textEdit`, you'll define a function that appends the appropriate text depending on the state in which you get.

```
void append( int i )
{
   switch ( i )
   {
      case MOVE_ID:
         textEdit->append( "move state" ) ;
         break ;
      case STOP_ID:
         textEdit->append( "stop state" ) ;
         break ;
   }
}
```